# Tabulator - Update Value of Custom Editor for Money Column

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I'm trying to update a money column value in a custom editor (because I want the decimal symbol, currency symbol and thousand symbol to show while editing - then I'll change it back when submitting)

Here's code so far (doesn't have symbols add or strip yet, just trying to get update to work properly.
There's a cellClick set up that calls the following code when cell format is type of money:

```
var inpck = $(mycell).find('input').length;

if (inpck == 1) {
    console.log('Input Already Exists'); 
    return;
}​​​​​​​

$(mycell).html($(mycell).find('input')); // remove text node of orig cell

$(mycell).append('<input type="text">'); // add input box

var editor = $(mycell).find('input');

//Set value of editor to the current value of the cell
console.log('Start Money Val: ' + celltxt); // shows correctly
editor.val(celltxt);

// Set focus on the input when the editor is selected (timeout allows for editor to be added to DOM)
editor.focus();

// After editing, trigger the cell to update on blur
editor.on("blur", function(e) {
  var editval = editor.val();
  alert('EditedValue: ' + editval); // shows correctly
  alert('CellID: ' + cellid); // shows correctly
  alert('CellField: ' + cellf); // shows correctly

  var updMonObj=[];
  updMonObj['id']=cellid;
  updMonObj[cellf]=editval;

  $("<tableid>").tabulator("updateData", updMonObj);
  $("<tableid>").tabulator("redraw");
});
```

After the alerts, the cell doesn't update and when I do a page refresh, the new value isn't coming in.  Would like the cell to update and show new value w/o refreshing the entire table if possible.

Would also like a way to update when they hit return.

Thanks

**Update1:**

Ok now I have this (running v3.2- have to stick w/ older version for now):

```
In the column definitions, I think this should work:
,editor: "moneyEdit1";

Then the tabulator call, and then further down:

var moneyEdit1 = function(cell, onRendered, success, cancel, editorParams) {
  //define custom editor
  var inpck = $(cell).find('input').length;
  if (inpck == 1) {console.log('Input Already Exists'); return;}
  console.log('Inside Money Edit');
  var mycell = cell.getElement();
  console.log('MyCell: ' , mycell);

  $(mycell).html($(mycell).find('input')); // remove text node
  $(mycell).append('<input type="text">');
  var editor = $(mycell).find('input');

  // Set value of editor to the current value of the cell
  console.log('Start Money Val: ' + celltxt);
  editor.val(celltxt);

  // Set focus on the input when the editor is selected
  onRendered(function() {
    editor.focus();
    editor.style.width = "100%";
  });

  // After editing, trigger the cell to update
  successFunc(function() {
    console.log('Inside of Change/Blur/Enter');
    var editval = editor.val();
    alert('EditedValue: ' + editval);
    success(editval);
  });

  // If they cancel w/ escape key
  cancelFunc(function() {
    console.log('Inside of Cancel');
    cancel(editval);
  });
  editor.addEventListener("change", successFunc);
  editor.addEventListener("blur", successFunc);
  editor.addEventListener("keyup", function onEvent(e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {successFunc;}
  });
  editor.addEventListener("keyup", function onEvent(e) {
    if (e.which === 27) {cancelFunc;}
  });
  // Return the editor element
  return editor;
}
```

Does that look like it should work?  Still doesn't call the custom editor, as I don't see any of the console logs, what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have missed of the function definition for that editor in your example code. In the [Editor Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.8/edit#edit-custom) you will see that there are two functions passed into the 3rd and 4th arguments of the function, ***success*** and ***cancel***

```js
var custom editor = function(cell, onRendered, success, cancel, editorParams){
   //define custom editor
}
```

you should call these function to let tabulator know that an edit has been successful or has been canceled.

In your editor you shouldnt be calling the ***updateData*** or ***redraw*** functions. Instead you should be calling the ***success*** function and passing the new value into it:

```js
success(editval);
```

Comment: just a bump to get your attention.

Comment: please create a JS fiddle that demonstrates the issue, it is very hard to offer advice without seeing the table in action